# How to filter multiple inside the list of list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, filtering

I have a model here which is `StudentModel` and have a property list of sanctions

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public List<UserSanctionModel> Sanctions { get; set; } = new List<UserSanctionModel>();
}
```

And this is my `UserSanctionModel`

```
public class UserSanctionModel
{
   public int SanctionId { get; set; }
}
```

And this the `param` Model

```
public class Parameter
{
    public List<Sanctions> Sanctions { get; set; } = new(); // list of sanction 
                                                                to be filter
}
```

I have tried this code but returning no values

```
students = students.
Where(s => param.Sanctions.Any( sanc => s.Sanctions.Any( s => s.SanctionId == sanc.SanctionId)))
.ToList();
```

`param.Sanctions` is a list which contains the ID of sanctions to be filter

EF Core Includes fully working

```
List<StudentModel> students =  await _context.Students
.Include( c => c.Course)
.Include( d => d.Department)
.Include( us => us.Sanctions).ThenInclude(s => s.Sanction)
.Include( s => s.Section).ToListAsync();


if (param.IsSanction)
{
    students = students.
    Where(s => param.Sanctions.Any( 
          sanc => s.Sanctions.Any( 
          s => s.SanctionId == sanc.SanctionId)))
    .ToList();
}
```

SanctionModel

```
public class Sanction
{
    SanctionId { get; set;}
    SanctionName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you fetching data with Entity Framework? If yes, you need to load the related entities with `Include()`. `students.Include(s => s.Sanctions).Where(...).ToList();`

Comment: I did but now how to filter

Comment: When you load related entities, EF will perform joining both entities and filter. Did you get any result? Would be great if you can share the DB data and input filter data.

Comment: fully working when `include` and `thenInclude` but if its all data but how about filtering `ChildrenList` to `list`

Comment: @YongShun i added the ef include to get the list

Comment: could you post the `Sanctions` class which in Parameter defination.

Comment: @QiangFu added please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

Can't find a way. As linq also use foreach, so maybe don't panic.

```
            var list = new List<StudentModel>();
            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                foreach (var s in student.Sanctions)
                {
                    foreach (var sanc in param.Sanctions)
                    {
                        if (s.SanctionId == sanc.SanctionId)
                        {
                            list.Add(student);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```